# How to exclude VSCode from WARP DNS changer?

Tags: networking, dns, visual-studio-code

I'm using [WARP](https://1.1.1.1/) for a protected connection and as a DNS changer. However, it affects the VSCode and my Copilot connection. Hence, I want to somehow enforce Windows to pass the internet traffic from the direct connection for VSCode.exe, not through the WARP connection. How can I define a specific routing rule for VSCode.exe? Unfortunately, WARP Desktop does not support excluding applications inherently.
The following options are available through WARP, but I don't find them helpful in my case:
[image]

Following harrymc's answer:
I excluded the domains that have been mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-firewall-settings-for-github-copilot#urls-to-add-to-an-allowlist). It does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

WARP is concerned with DNS and routes, not with programs.
You must therefore find the domains that VSCode is attempting to use
and exclude them from WARP. There is no other method in WARP itself.

The method to use is part of
[Cloudflare Zero Trust](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/)
and involves the need to
[Configure Split Tunnels](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-devices/warp/configure-warp/route-traffic/split-tunnels/).

You will find more information in the article
[Traffic routing with WARP](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-devices/warp/configure-warp/route-traffic/).

Comment: I tried this. I excluded all IP addresses that Copilot might use. It does not work.

Comment: What does not work ?

Comment: Your workaround. I tried it in the past.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some details inside your post about how exactly you have tried this. Because it has to work.

Comment: What is the problem that you encounter? Timeouts?

Comment: It's not about Timeout. Long story. I'm from Iran and we are restricted from using GH Copilot according to GH terms of use and policy. So, usually, I set a DNS on my network to kinda bypass the restriction. On the other hand, our filthy government has restricted Iranians' access to many websites and we need a DNS changer or a VPN. But, when I use WARP to access those websites, it kinda reveals my location to GH Copilot and it says GHC is not available in your country. So, I can't use WARP and GHC simultaneously.

Comment: I understand your problem, but I'm not using your environment and can't do any testing. I think that the list you found is probably not complete, so some connection escapes through. I can only advise to use a debug tool such as Fiddler or Wireshark to find out this domain.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, you can't do any investigation. I'm not familiar with the tools you've mentioned. However, I will check them out, and hopefully manage to use them.

Comment: Good luck and good coding.

Comment: Thank you so much, good luck to you, and love. ❤️